# How to Opeen a parent window while opening a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to close the parent window when a new window is opened.

I tried top.window.close() but it did not work for me.

Does anybody here know any other method to get a collection of windows

Comment: Sorry but looks like your title doesn't fit with your question which doesn't fit with the content of your topic. Can you ask a clear question?

Comment: can you please explain on how to use the opener property?

Comment: window.opener.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume, you have a page called **"PageA"**, in **"PageA"** you can open **"PageB"** , by this `window.open` like `window.open("PageB")` and in **"PageB"** you can access the `window` object of **"PageA** by this `window.opener`, and to close **"PageA"** from **"PageB"** you can use this `window.opener.close()`, to see complete `window.open` sample, read this [Window.open API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

and to review `window.opener` see this [Window.opener API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener)